# driver.execute() TypeError elem[prop] is not a function in NodeJs WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, ui-automation, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I am trying highlight a element. Please help me on this code. (I am a beginner to nodejs)

```
    class Utilities {
    
        async highlight(element){
               await browser.execute((userelement)=>{
                    userelement.style.backgroundColor="red";
                 },element);
                }
    
    }

module.exports = new Utilities();
```

---

in Stepdef :

```
Utilities.highlight(LoginPage.getusername);
```

---

in PageObjects:

```
class LoginPage{
    get getusername(){
        return $('#username');
    }
}
```

---

Error :

```
TypeError: elem[prop] is not a function
    at \node_modules\@wdio\utils\build\shim.js:253:38
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)..
```

---

Detailed Error Log:

> [0-0] 2022-07-18T12:50:08.380Z INFO webdriver: DATA { [0-0]   script:
> 'return ((userelement)=>{\r\n' + [0-0]     '
> userelement.style.backgroundColor="red";\r\n' + [0-0]     '
> }).apply(null, arguments)', [0-0]   args: [ Promise {  } ]
> [0-0] } [0-0] 2022-07-18T12:50:08.398Z INFO webdriver: RESULT { [0-0]
> 'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf':
> 'be8745a8-6499-482b-af98-8dc191b88452' [0-0] } [0-0] Error in "0: When
> I login with nithildani and asdas123" TypeError: elem[prop] is not a
> function
> at C:\Users\nitarula\Documents\Sample2\node_modules@wdio\utils\build\shim.js:253:38
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) [0-0]
> 2022-07-18T12:50:08.417Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND deleteSession() [0-0]
> 2022-07-18T12:50:08.417Z INFO webdriver: [DELETE]
> http://localhost:9515/session/36ae82293a3b853a2965d478c51f4235 [0-0]
> 2022-07-18T12:50:08.425Z INFO webdriver: RESULT { [0-0]
> 'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf':
> '66da9a07-388f-445c-90ef-9c7a12c29856' [0-0] } [0-0]
> 2022-07-18T12:50:08.429Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND
> elementClear("66da9a07-388f-445c-90ef-9c7a12c29856") [0-0]
> 2022-07-18T12:50:08.429Z INFO webdriver: [POST]
> http://localhost:9515/session/36ae82293a3b853a2965d478c51f4235/element/66da9a07-388f-445c-90ef-9c7a12c29856/clear
> [0-0] 2022-07-18T12:50:08.438Z WARN webdriver: Request failed with
> status 500 due to javascript error: Cannot set properties of undefined
> (setting 'backgroundColor') [0-0]   (Session info:
> chrome=103.0.5060.114) [0-0] 2022-07-18T12:50:08.439Z INFO webdriver:
> Retrying 1/3 [0-0] 2022-07-18T12:50:08.439Z INFO webdriver: [POST]
> http://localhost:9515/session/36ae82293a3b853a2965d478c51f4235/execute/sync
> [0-0] 2022-07-18T12:50:08.440Z INFO webdriver: DATA { [0-0]   script:
> 'return ((userelement)=>{\r\n' + [0-0]     '
> userelement.style.backgroundColor="red";\r\n' + [0-0]     '
> }).apply(null, arguments)', [0-0]   args: [ Promise { [Element] } ]
> [0-0] } [0-0]
> C:\Users\nitarula\Documents\Sample2\node_modules@wdio\utils\build\shim.js:253
> [0-0]                     return elemprop; [0-0]
> ^ [0-0] [0-0] TypeError: elem[prop] is not a function [0-0]     at
> C:\Users\nitarula\Documents\Sample2\node_modules@wdio\utils\build\shim.js:253:38
> [0-0]     at processTicksAndRejections
> (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) { [0-0]
> [Symbol(originalCallSite)]: [ CallSite {}, CallSite {} ], [0-0]
> [Symbol(mutatedCallSite)]: [ CallSite {}, CallSite {} ] [0-0] } [0-0]
> FAILED in chrome -
> C:\Users\nitarula\Documents\Sample2\features\login.feature
> 2022-07-18T12:50:08.499Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerEnd hook
> 2022-07-18T12:50:08.502Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hoo

Thanks in Advance

Comment: which version of nodejs are you on?

Comment: can you add more logs pointing to the location of error?

Comment: I have edited the detailed error log. Thanks for your time

Comment: node version : v16.16.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code was that your input to `browser.execute()` does not work in a browser context. It will not have access to your webdriverio queried elements. Instead, you should pass something which works in a browser context. So, you have to pass a selector instead of the selected element.

```js
  async highlightById(element) {
    await browser.execute((arg) => {
      document.querySelector(arg).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }, element);
  }
```

```js
await Utilities.highlightById('#username');
or
await Utils.highlightById(`#${await LoginPage.getUsername.getAttribute('id')}`);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Raju. Can you please let me know which is ES5 version and what is added in ES6. and why my code is breaking.

Comment: module.exports and require are from ES5. classes, export, and import are from ES6. Your code has some spelling mistakes as well. You are trying to call a non-existent method.

Comment: Thank you. while pasting the code here I misspelled it.. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hi @Raju I added all your code and corrected all spellchecks. Still I am getting the same error. But if I comment that Utils.highlight() in stepdef my code is running fine. any other possiblities?

Comment: [0-0] 2022-07-18T17:22:50.114Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND executeScript("return (userElement => {
[0-0]       userElement.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
[0-0]     }).apply(null, arguments)", <object>).....
TypeError: elem[prop] is not a function
    at C:\Users\nitarula\Documents\Sample2\node_modules\@wdio\utils\build\shim.js:253:38....
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
 Request failed with status 500 due to javascript error: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'backgroundColor')

Comment: Do you have the code somewhere I can access it?

Comment: Have uploaded to Github click [here](https://github.com/nithildani93/Sample2.git) to access it

Comment: The only repo updated about 17 yrs ago is https://github.com/nithildani93/wdioSamples. I don't see any code there. Maybe your repo is private?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246576/discussion-between-nithilan-and-raju).